# How many sub-tuples keep the same cardinality ordering of the original tuple

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Let $I=\{1,\ldots,N\}$ and $r = (r_1,\ldots, r_T) \in I^{T}$.

The cardinality of an object $i$ of $I$ in a sequence $s$ of length $T$ is given by $n_i(s) = \sum_{t=1}^T I(s_t=i)$.

Let $C$ be an integer such :that $1\leq C < N$. Let $S(s)$ be the set that contains all the sets of objects with the $C$ highest cardinalities for sequence $s$. For example when $n_i(s) =n_j(s) \; \forall i,j, \; $ $S(s)$ contains all the possible subsets of $I$ of size $C$.

The total number of subsequences of $r$ of length $l$ is $\binom{T}{l}$. What is the fraction of subsequences of $r$ with length $l$: $s$, for which $S(s) \subset S(r)$ as a function of $n_i(r),T, l$ and $C$?